# Solana blockchain. How can i generate private key?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, private, private-key, solana

```
       const solanaWeb3 = require("@solana/web3.js");
    const solanatoken = require("@solana/spl-token");
    
      var wallet = solanaWeb3.Keypair.generate();
      console.log("public key...", wallet.publicKey);
      console.log("secret key...", wallet.secretKey);
    
      console.log("secret key...", JSON.stringify(wallet.secretKey.toString()));`enter preformatted text here`
```

I got

```
public key... PublicKey {
  _bn: <BN: b5ec974285759f4004555c6890e045a4ce857c6a056895d77dd209c054e76556>
secret key... "211,55,244,72,160,174,33,152,24,226,97,172,91,91,47,3,148,83,99,188,150,111,153,248,253,237,31,223,194,194,199,0,181,236,151,66,133,117,159,64,4,85,92,104,144,224,69,164,206,133,124,106,5,104,149,215,125,210,9,192,84,231,101,86"
```

how I can get `private key`, like

> kNykCXNxgePDjFbDWjPNvXQRa8U12Ywc19dFVaQ7tebUj3m7H4sF4KKdJwM7yxxb3rqxchdjezX9Szh8bLcQAjb

for use on the phantom wallet?
docs: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Keypair.html

Answer (score 5):

If you want the private key in base58, you'll have to do a conversion.

`wallet.secretKey` gives a `Uint8Array`: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Keypair.html#secretKey, so you'll have to convert from `Uint8Array` to a base58 string.

There are packages to do that, and Solana's web3 package uses `bs58`: https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/bs58#encodeinput

So you'll have to do `bs58.encode(wallet.secretKey)` to get the string as you're expecting.

Answer (score 4):

for use on the phantom wallet you can copy and paste byte array directly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can change UInt8Array to String like "kNykCXNxgePDjFbDWjPNvXQRa8U12Ywc19dFVaQ7tebUj3m7H4sF4KKdJwM7yxxb3rqxchdjezX9Szh8bLcQAjb" by using bs58.encode() or PublicKey.toBase58();

```
let secretKey = keyPair.secretKey.toBase58();
```

Comment: You will get `TypeError: wallet.secretKey.toBase58 is not a function`

Comment: I tried this and I got `TypeError: myKeypair.secretKey.toBase58 is not a function` . This solves the problem `bs58.encode(wallet.secretKey)`